# want to change the cursor on mouse move on JTree listed elements

Tags: java, swing, cursor, jlist, jtree

I want to change the cursor to hand cursor on mouse move over `JTree` component when the cursor is on listed elements only, not for the whole component.

The below code is for `Jlist` Component. I want same for the `JTree`, but `JTree` *does not have* `getCellBound()`.  Is there any other way?

```
final JList list = new JList(new String[] {"a","b","c"});
list.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionListener() {
@Override
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    final int x = e.getX();
    final int y = e.getY();
    // only display a hand if the cursor is over the items
    final Rectangle cellBounds = list.getCellBounds(0, list.getModel().getSize() - 1);
    if (cellBounds != null && cellBounds.contains(x, y)) {
        list.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
    } else {
        list.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
    }
}

@Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
}
});
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: I don't get what the problem is. It seems to work for me. And your title says "JTree" but your code says "JList": which one is it?

Comment: @Guillaume Polet : forget the code,simply i want the hand cursor on Jtree component only when the cursor is moving over the displayed element not when the cursor is on any part of the JTree component,Bydefault it displays normal cursor on any part of the JTree

Comment: @GuillaumePolet forget the code,simply i want the hand cursor on Jtree component only when the cursor is moving over the displayed element not when the cursor is on any part of the JTree component,Bydefault it displays normal cursor on any part of the JTree

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for something like this, I guess:

```
import java.awt.Cursor;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeModel;
import javax.swing.tree.TreePath;

public class TestTreeSelection {

    protected void initUI() {
        final DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Root");
        fillTree(root, 5, "Some tree label");
        final DefaultTreeModel model = new DefaultTreeModel(root);
        final JTree tree = new JTree(model);
        tree.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                boolean inside = false;
                TreePath path = tree.getPathForLocation(e.getX(), e.getY());
                if (path != null) {
                    Rectangle pathBounds = tree.getPathBounds(path);
                    inside = pathBounds.contains(e.getPoint());
                }
                if (inside) {
                    tree.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
                } else {
                    tree.setCursor(Cursor.getDefaultCursor());
                }
            }
        });
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(new JScrollPane(tree));
        f.setSize(400, 600);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void fillTree(DefaultMutableTreeNode parent, int level, String label) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            DefaultMutableTreeNode node = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(label + " " + i);
            parent.add(node);
            if (level > 0) {
                fillTree(node, level - 1, label);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TestTreeSelection().initUI();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works:

```
        tree_object.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionListener() {

                @Override
                public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                    TreePath tp = ((JTree)e.getSource()).getPathForLocation(e.getX(), e.getY());

                    if(tp != null)
                    {
                        ((JTree)e.getSource()).setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ((JTree)e.getSource()).setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
                    }
                }
         });
```